# Flutter String is in Future null

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I want to use a string in this function that has the phone number of the device.
I get the phone number with this:

```
Future<void> initMobilNumberState() async {
    if (!await MobileNumber.hasPhonePermission) {
      await MobileNumber.requestPhonePermission;
      return;
    }
    String mobileNumber = '';

    try {
      mobileNumber = await MobileNumber.mobileNumber;
      _simCard = await MobileNumber.getSimCards;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Failed to get mobile number because of '${e.message}'");
    }

    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      var re = RegExp(r'\+[^]*');
      _mobileNumber = mobileNumber.replaceRange(0, 3, ''.replaceAll(re, '+'));
    });
  }
```

My problem is that if I want to print _mobileNumber or use it in http.get I get null or a error with "Invalid Arguments"

```
  Future<http.Response> _fetchSampleData() async {
    String s = _mobileNumber;
    print(s);
    return http.get('http://test.php?TestPhone=' + _mobileNumber);
  }

  Future<void> getDataFromServer() async {
    final response = await _fetchSampleData();
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
      _list = data.values.toList();
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      showAlertNoInternet(context);
      print('Failed to load data from server');
    }
  }
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: I think _mobileNumber never fill after setState(), try to print _mobileNumber after it, to make sure data is correct fill in _mobileNumber.

Comment: @mam_65 I have printed it and it is filled with it.

Comment: Okay I believe that the initMobilNumberState will be executed completely only last. So in the _fetchSampleData the _mobilNumber is null. Is there a possibility to change the order? So that _fetchSampleData is execute at last? @mam_65

Comment: I think this line `  if (!mounted) return;` in last causes the `setState()` not run and `_mobileNumber` always is `null`, first be sure  `initMobilNumberState()` work.You can not change the order. first you must fill the  `_mobileNumber` and then call `_fetchSampleData` or any method can use `_mobileNumber` OK?

Comment: @mam_65 Okay thanks to you I managed it I will post my correct code shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I want to call the phone number before it has even been fetched. So this always resulted in null. I fixed this by fetching the number when I start the app with all the other data I need.